# Graphene batteries/super capacitors

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, capacitance, superconductivity, graphene

A while ago, there was some news about micro-scale graphene-based supercapacitors and these devices can charge and discharge a hundred to a thousand times faster than standard batteries.

**Question:**
Which properties of graphene enables it to charge and discharge hundreds of times faster than standard batteries? Is it because graphene provides larger surface area?

---

In addition, the news also said they can be easily integrated into electric devices. It sounds too good to be true and I would like to know if there are any downside/limitation to this technology.(Maybe they are expensive but developers have recently found a cheaper method to produce them using DVD burners)

Answer (score 2):

There are really two separate parts to your question:

1. what is the difference between a supercapacitor and a battery?
2. why does graphene make such good supercapacitors?

A battery and a supercapacitor work in very different ways. A battery generates electricity using a chemical reaction. As the reaction procedes a current is generated, and once the reagents have all been used up the reaction stops and the battery is exhausted. The current that a battery can generate depends on the rate of the reaction and the internal resistance of the battery and is generally limited. However it's easy to store a lot of energy as chemical energy, so batteries can produce a lot of power before they run down.

By contrast a capacitor stores electrons directly. The sort of capacitor in the computer I'm using to type this is basically a [parallel plate capacitor](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/pplate.html). Capacitors like this have virtually zero internal resistance, so the charge can flow off them at very high speeds (i.e. high currents) but each capacitor can store only a small amount of charge, so they store much less energy than a battery.

A [supercapacitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercapacitor) stores electrons directly, like a parallel plate capacitor, but using a different mechanism that can store much more energy. Carbon based superconductors use a porous carbon matrix with a liquid electrolyte, and they store the electrons in an [electric double layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_double-layer_capacitor) at the carbon surface. The amount of energy this type of supercapacitor can store is comparable to a battery, so they combine a high energy density with very low internal resistance.

Exactly how graphene improves on existing supercapacitors I'm not sure. I imagine the details will be kept secret until all the patents have been acquired! From the articles I've seen on the web I'd guess it's a combination of the very high surface area that can be achieved using graphene electrodes. Obviously the greater the carbon/electrolyte contact area the greater the energy that can be stored in the double layer. In addition graphene is a far better conductor than the amorphous carbon used in existing supercapacitors.

**Later:**

If anyone is still interested, there has just been a paper on the Arxiv describing graphene supercapacitors. See [Graphene based Supercapacitors with Improved Specific Capacitance and Fast Charging Time at High Current Density](http://arxiv.org/abs/1311.1548) and the [summary at the Arxiv blog](http://www.technologyreview.com/view/521651/graphene-supercapacitors-ready-for-electric-vehicle-energy-storage-say-korean-engineers/).